# Don't understand what Sharepoint version I'm using

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, version

It seems that I'm using SharePoint Foundation 2013, because I can't run certain functions like I can't choose workflow platform 2013 in SharePoint Designer. However, when I run SharePoint SERVER 2013 setup, it lets me to choose if I want to repair or remove. So what the hell? Install says that SharePoint Server is installed while PowerShell and other tools speaks differently.

Answer (score 0):

Open Central Administration and click Manage Farm Features under the System Settings section.

If you are running SharePoint Server or Enterprise you should see a number of deactivated options which you can click on to activate.